# Column Depending on Others

Tags: database, relational-database, normalization, database-normalization

I have the following table:

[image]

My gut tells me it's bad because `TOTAL` can be deduced from `TIME_IN` and `TIME_OUT`.

Of what normal form is this a breach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing values that are the result of calculations usually violates 3NF. They constitute a transitive dependency.

In your case, the transitive dependency is

```
time_in, time_out -> total
```

The pair {time_in, time_out} is *not* a candidate key.

Normally (ahem), you'd resolve transitive dependencies by projection, but that doesn't usually make sense when the transitive dependency involves the results of calculations.  There are three obvious options.

- Drop the column "total", and calculate it in each query.
- Drop the column "total", and build a view (or a materialized view) that calculates the total.
- Keep the column "total" and add a CHECK() constraint to guarantee the value is always right.

Each of these might have different effects on performance and maintenance.